# Python Nested Lists Bracket Removal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a program which chooses random items from lists imported from text documents that are associated with the topic e.g. food in eats contains pizza,pasta and burgers. However, when it prints out the result the chosen items have parentheses, square brackets and speech marks. how would i remove them?

```
things_to_do=[
("eat", [(foods[randint(0,20)])]),
("do", [(sports[randint(0,60)])]),
("drink a",[(coffees[randint(0,20)])])]



print "Whilst in town you decided to " + str(things_to_do[randint(0,2)])]
```

Comment: use the `replace()` method, e.g. ("(", "")

Comment: Read about how to create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These brackets, quotes, etc. are just part of the [string representation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) of more complex data structures such as [`lists`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) or [`tuples`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple). You need to properly prepare/format your data for nicer output:

```
things_to_do = [
  ("eat", foods[randint(0,20)]),  # less complex than the singleton lists in your code
  ("do", sports[randint(0,60)]),
  ("drink a", coffees[randint(0,20)])
]
verb, obj = things_to_do[randint(0,2)]
print "Whilst in town you decided to {v} {o}".format(v=verb, o=obj)
```

[String formatting in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Comment: Thanks! it really helped!

Answer (score 0):

Use `yourVar[start, end]` to print your string between the start and the end character, for example if my text is `myVar = "[(hello)]"` `myVar[3:-3]` will show `hello`

Comment: however it combines two variables and they can be completely different lengths e.g. ('drink a', ['white wine']) or ('eat', ['pizza'])

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are not printing strings but tuples, and lists.

```
print "Hi my name is "+str(("really",["Tom"]))
```

leads to

```
Hi my name is ('really', ['Tom'])
```

So you want to access/manipulate your variables to print strings

- use [0] to access an item in your tuple or list
- print items in an array like this ','.join(yourArray)
- or even better use format! https://pyformat.info/ "hi {0}".format("tom")